# Mapping .csv file using ArcGIS online with Python

Tags: arcgis-online, arcgis-python-api

I have .csv data in the format:

```
Longitude Latitude Threat
  -24         45     0.5
  -31         40     0.9
   .          .       .
   .          .       .
```

I want to visualize this data as a threat level heat map in Python. So far I have figured out how to get the csv data into my ArcGIS Online account with this:

```py
import arcgis
from arcgis.gis import GIS
from arcgis.mapping import WebMap
import os


gis = GIS("https://www.arcgis.com", "USERNAME", 
"PASSWORD")
data_path = (r"C:\Users\NAME\Desktop\Map")
csv_path = os.path.join(data_path, "mapUS2061FINAL.csv")
csv_properties={'title':'hwa2061',
            'description':'hwa2061',
            'tags':'arcgis, python'}

thumbnail_path = os.path.join(data_path, "hwa.png")

earthquake_csv_item = 
   gis.content.add(item_properties=csv_properties, 
   data=csv_path, thumbnail =thumbnail_path)
```

How would I visualize this csv data from Python on a map, and then save this map or the html code for the map to my computer?

I am new to GIS.

I put the .csv in a DataFrame and converted into a Feature Layer. It was successfully sent to ArcGIS but when I try and view the Feature Layer, I was stuck on a loading page which probably indicates that my data input was incorrect.

Here is what I tried:

```py
import json
from IPython.display import display
import arcgis
from arcgis.gis import GIS
from arcgis.mapping import WebMap, WebScene
import pandas as pd

gis = GIS("https://www.arcgis.com", "USERNAME", "PASSWORD")
f = open("C:/Users/NAME/PycharmProjects/colors/Map/mapUS2061ADDADDADD.csv")
df = pd.read_csv(f)
print (df.head ())
x=gis.content.import_data(df)

y = dict(x.properties)
z = json.dumps({"featureCollection": {"layers": [y]}})
p = {'title': 'hwa2060#9',
                    'snippet':'hwa',
                    'description':'test ' + \
                    'dataframe object to a GIS item',
                    'text':z,
                    'type':'Feature Collection',
                    'tags': 'python'
                     }
h = gis.content.add(p)
display(h)
```

Python Output:

```
    X   y    Threat
0  -74  40   0.127
1 -114  47   0.000
2  -79  25   0.158
3  -89  43   0.109
4 -106  37   0.068
<Item title:"hwa2060#9" type:Feature Collection owner:USERNAME>
```

When I went to ArcGIS Online, the map did not show up. It was stuck loading.

I want to then put this feature layer on a map and export the html code from this map eventually.

Comment: Have you reviewed the help page [here](https://developers.arcgis.com/python/guide/accessing-and-creating-content/) about creating content?

Comment: Yes, I think the issue may be when I do .publish (). An error saying I do not have permissions was thrown when I had this in my code so I took it out. That is probably why the map is not showing up.

Comment: What type of ArcGIS Online account is this? If it’s a free public one, I would recommend taking a look at the terms of use for the free developer plan.